# Batch editing audio files

Tags: audio, batch

I have about 85 ogg files that I need to edit. What I need to do is clip off the beginning of each one, as there is some silence at the beginning. This is not uniform across the files. Audacity seems to have a batch processing mode, but I can't figure out how to clip audio with it. The ideal solution would be one that scans the file for when sound starts and clips off anything before that. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Personally I use [mp3trim](http://www.mptrim.com/) for those tasks

Comment: I will give this a try once I get on Windows. Thanks!